# Does RevenueCat's SDK for iOS allows to detect storefront country change

Tags: ios, storefront, revenuecat

I'm considering RevenueCat for implementation of in-app subscriptions for one of the clients. The client wants to limit the number of countries where in-app subscriptions are available.

Question: Does the RevenueCat's SDK for iOS allows to detect changes of storefront country as the StoreKit does? Please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorefront  for storekit reference.

Thanks,
Aliaksandr.

Comment: You might get a quicker response by just engaging their support team directly: https://support.revenuecat.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0):

No, RevenueCat will never block a purchase from going through Apple if the customer tries to purchase a product. You'd want to set this limitation on the product or app in App Store Connect by only offering it in the countries you want to sell it in.